# How can i upload attachments to Quickbook Desktop via Quickbook Web Connector

Tags: qbxml, qbwc

I'm working to sync data such as invoice, purchase order, sales order,... from my application to client's Quickbook Desktop via Quickbook Web Connector.

But i don't know how can i upload attachments. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The SDK does not support uploading documents.